# How to use config information in seeds and rake tasks? (Rails 4.1.x)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

Not sure if you would actually do this. So please suggest other ways if you wish.

I am looking to create a config file for a rails engine that you can either create for your project or use the config file in the engine its self.

This config file would contain default names for things like roles, groups and permissions.

The idea is if you create this config file in your project that implement the engine, we will use those default names you have specified through out the seed file and through out things like the controller actions to assign to and check for these specific groups, roles and permissions.

An example is, in the check for `is_admin?` I look to see if a user belongs to an `Admin` role.

Well in your app you might have called that `Super User`. So thats where this config file would come in handy, it would allow you to create your own names for default groups and roles and so on with out worrying about breaking the engine or with out the engine having to hard code things.

You could still use `is_admin?` and instead of checking for `Admin` role it would now know to check for `Super User`.

So my question is:

- How do I remove hard coded checks for column names and replace them with "global" variables you can configure in your app or that are configured in the rails engine?
- How do I allow users to create their own config file that the engine knows about when you go to "install" the engine in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exposing engine's config is a pretty simple task. Using my engine as an example:

Actual configuration file. This is where you can set your defaults.

- https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/blob/master/lib/comfortable_mexican_sofa/configuration.rb

This way whatever is defined in that class is accessible via `ComfortableMexicanSofa.config.some_config_option`

Now you need a nice way to expose configuration:

- https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/blob/master/lib/comfortable_mexican_sofa.rb

This is so it's possible to have this kind of interface:

```
ComfortableMexicanSofa.configure do |config|
  config.cms_title = 'My Custom title'
end
```

So now you can have initializer that you can move to host app with a generator:

- https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/blob/master/config/initializers/comfortable_mexican_sofa.rb

So now you can use configuration to make your `is_admin?` method more flexible. Of course there's always an option to completely override engine's stuff from the host application.

Comment: I am hoping people don't over ride things, hence the configuration file. Thanks for this.